# Advanced Settings don't get saved (Wygwam)

Tags: wygwam

I'm using EE 2.8.0 and updated to Wygwam 3.3. I'm adding some advanced settings in the Wygwam configuration (eg.g for the Basic set) in the CP - when saving and going back to the Wygwam configuration page, all the advanced settings are lost.

Anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Same here. Wygwam 3.3 and EE 2.8
Advanced settings not saved....

Comment: Yes me too - EE 2.8.0 and Wygwam 3.3.1 - advanced settings just disappear after a save

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the advanced settings do appear to get saved - they just don't appear again on the Editor Configurations page. This seems to be a bug which prevents the display of the advanced configurations rather than a bug in saving them. The advanced configurations I saved were available for use on the publish page.